# Set ManyToManyField with particular users from another model's ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a simple class group app in which I am trying to add particular users from another model's `ManyToFieldField` to a new model's `ManyToFieldField`.

```
class ClassGroup(models.Model):
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='admins')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AITH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=9999, default='')

class ClassGroupInvite(models.Model):
    class_group = models.ForeignKey(ClassGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invite_receiver = models.ManyToManyField(class_group.admins.all())
    invite_sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As you can see that I am filtering (send request only to class group admins) in **ClassGroupInvite** with setting `ManyToManyField` with `ClassGroup.admins`

But when I try this then it is showing

> ManyToManyField(<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyToManyDescriptor object at 0x000001CE78793280>) is invalid. First parameter to ManyToManyField must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'

I also read the documentation about it, But I didn't find anything about defining it.

then I tried using `ClassGroup.admins.all` then it showed

> AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

I have tried many times but it is still not working, Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: `classgroup.admins.all() should work only if classgroup is an instance of a model not the model itself and note that it is not a good idea to have related_name as the same name as the field name.`

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow, I have created field in `ClassGroupInvite` linked `ForeignKey` with `ClassGroup` but when i use it like `classgroup.admins.all()` then it is showing, **AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'admins'**

Comment: could you show the query you wrote ?

Comment: what does this mean `invite_receiver = models.ManyToManyField(class_group.admins.all())` why not just use this `invite_receiver = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`

Comment: I want to send the `invite` only to `class group admins`.

Comment: look it does not work like that you already has foreignkey to `ClassGroup` so you can put this `invite_receiver = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` but when adding a user you can check whether the user is already in admins of th classgroup.

Comment: I think you're right, I can do that in views. Thanks for your Time. I already thought about doing in views, I also thought that this may not be the best idea of doing in views. But Thanks Again

Comment: you are welcome but if you know that sometimes will need to add user through the django admin then you can use django signals to handle this or over write the save method.

Comment: are you trying to have default value (i..e. all admins for your M2M relation) for your `ClassGroupInvite` objects (I mean all of it's related objects)??? or you just want to add them for some specific objects?